# How to point menu to my homepage

Tags: menus, widgets

So basicially i have a long-long homepage where you can scroll down and find a services section, if you scroll down more you see important informations and etc. but i have a menu. I want to make the buttons on the menu to scroll me down to that section so for example if i click sercives it scrolls me down to services on my main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add "Custom Links" to your menu to point to the homepage + the specific anchor on the page.

For example, your `services` section may have the markup:

```
<section id="services">
   <h2>Services</h2>
   <p>Some text</p>
</section>
```

So your custom menu link would need to have a URL of `/#services`. You need the `/` slash at the start so that if someone clicks the menu from elsewhere in the site, it will first go to the homepage and then link to services, rather than trying to look for that ID on the current page.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my problem!